# In HTTP, Prompt to Save and XML File Rather Then Render

Tags: xml, http, http-headers

In a Web Application I am creating, users can backup their data locally.  The backup data is an XML file.  At the moment, most browsers try to display this file.  What should I change in the HTTP response to suggest to a user-agent that the file should instead be saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Content-Disposition header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_backup.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use content disposition like:

```
AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=MyExportedFile.xml");
```

This will give you a save prompt rather than attempt to render to screen